# Trouble with Date in JNI

Tags: java, c++, date, java-native-interface

I need to pass Java Date argument to a Java method from my C++ project using JNI.

```
jclass date = env->FindClass("java/util/Date");
if (env->ExceptionCheck()){
  cout << "Fail:";
}
jmethodID dateTypeConstructor= env->GetMethodID(date, "<init>", "()V");
if(dateTypeConstructor == nullptr){
  cout << "Fail:";
}
jobject dateObjectStart = env->NewObject(date, dateTypeConstructor);
if(dateObjectStart  == nullptr){
  cout << "Fail:";
}
long a = env->CallLongMethod(dateObjectStart,gettIME);
```

Through Debugging i take the value of `a` which is `582106004` . This value is the msec that have passed since 1 January 1970.
The same code, instantiating a Date object and getting the time, in Java gives me the value `1400741921774` that is the correct one.

Why is this happening? I am suspescting problem with JDK because in my C++/JNI project i ma using JDK 1.8 while Java/util/Date is a bit Deprecated.

Comment: ok, turning `long a` to `double a` seems to give more reasonable values..

Comment: Not `Java.util.Date` itself is deprecated - just the constructor that takes a single string. How is `gettIME` defined in your code?

Comment: Also make sure to use 'jlong' (which is always 64bits) - and not just `long`. Depending on your architecture and java vm (32Bit/64Bit) - These can actually make a difference there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output from the following code:

```
jclass date = env->FindClass("java/util/Date");
if (env->ExceptionCheck()){
  std::cout << "Fail:";
}
jmethodID dateTypeConstructor= env->GetMethodID(date, "<init>", "()V");
if(dateTypeConstructor == nullptr){
  std::cout << "Fail:";
}
jobject dateObjectStart = env->NewObject(date, dateTypeConstructor);
if(dateObjectStart  == nullptr){
  std::cout << "Fail:";
}
jmethodID getTime = env->GetMethodID(date, "getTime", "()J");
if(getTime == nullptr){
  std::cout << "Fail:";
}
jlong a = env->CallLongMethod(dateObjectStart, getTime);
std::cout << a << std::endl;
```

is on my machine (JNI, 1.6 JDK):

```
1400754723399
```

Which seems correctly to me - Also make sure to use `jlong` (which is always 64bits) - and not just `long` (which could be 32 bit - depending on your architecture) - These can actually make a difference there. If you turn on compiler warnings, the line

```
long a = env->CallLongMethod(dateObjectStart, getTime);
```

should raise an compiler warning anyway.

Comment: That is correct!An alternative method is to declare it as `double`!

Comment: Yes, if you use double as variable type, it will implicit cast the jlong value to an double value.